# Starting new project with Cordova 2-7-0, cannot create in command line

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am trying to create a new porject with the latest version of cordova. I am following the instructions [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS) but I get stuck at the Start New Project command line section

I follow the instruction where it says open the command line tool, drop the 'bin' file in and enter the following:

`./create ~/Documents/CordovaXY/HelloWorld org.apache.cordova.HelloWorld HelloWorld`

But when I hit enter all the command line says is

`No such file or directory`

Is there anyway to do this without using command line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it was my stupid fault for not reading the instructions properly. I dragged the `bin` directory into the already open terminal window, instead of onto the **Terminal Icon in the Dock**

Answer (score 0):

Using the command line is probably the easiest way to do it, so keep trying!

I would run just the command

```
./create
```

without parameters. If you get a warning message and a list of possible flags and parameters then this means that your problem is in the parameters

```
~/Documents/CordovaXY/HelloWorld org.apache.cordova.HelloWorld HelloWorld
```

and not the command itself.

My guess is that you have to create the CordovaXY directory.

Otherwise, double check that the 'Xcode Command Line Tools' are correctly installed. The page you linked states "Cordova uses the command line to create a new application project. To access the Xcode tools from the command line an additional download is required."

Comment: Thanks I have tried entering ./create but all it returns is ' No such file or directory'